# How do I localize my game?

Tags: localization

My team and I are making a game to support multiple languages, and we want to work on localizing the game to reach a wider audience.

Where would I start? How would this be accomplished? I would work on providing different scripts with multiple languages and there would be more than one language to translate to.

What are the techniques and tools used to localize games?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? Do you mean you want to create a translator from a human language to an existing computer language?

Comment: Too broad is a problem here too.  Suggested reading: [where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6366/40980)

Comment: Why do you need to translate? Do you need to be able to translate back?

Comment: I am interested in trying to answer this.  Can you provide a sample and how you would translate it?  It is just word substitution or is the grammar of the two radically different?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah just word substitution.

Comment: @Dubstaphone - If you are new here I recommend you improve your communication. Multiple people were interested in helping you but you ignored my question and gave a cryptic answer to Jerry's. It wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why people down-voted your answer. "Localization in gaming" is an interesting topic.

More precisely, we call this task "localization the game". Localization in gaming is the process of translating and releasing your game in other languages (or accents, depends on your needs). Localization lets your game reach a larger audience, increasing your fan base and potential sales.

I recommend that you start reading this thread [How to prepare a game for localization?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/679/how-to-prepare-a-game-for-localization), there are some good insights in the comments.

Check these articles as well:

- http://company.plarium.com/news/featured/how-game-developers-can-overcome-localization-challenges/
- http://www.localization.it/the-future-of-game-localization-interview-with-localizedirects-christoffer-nilsson
- http://translation-blog.com/?s=game

Check this course:

- http://www.udemy.com/course-introduction-to-game-localization/

I am not sure which technology you use, Unity, .. but you can be inspired by [Mozilla localization tools](https://wiki.mozilla.org/L10n:Tools)

Comment: Essentially, that's a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @JensG Yes! But the man seems to have no-idea from he start. It's better to give him some good resources to do his first baby-steps then Copy/Paste from those links.